# Cannot connect to SQL Alias through PowerShell

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I have a development VM setup as a domain controller with SQL Server 2012 installed.  I am trying to connect directly on the server, but am unable to connect to my SQL Alias via PowerShell using the following commands:

```
$sqlServer = "sp2013sql"
$objSQLConnection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$objSQLCommand = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$objSQLConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$sqlServer;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
$objSQLConnection.Open()
```

I can directly through SQL Server Management Studio using the `sp2013sql` SQL Alias and via the name of the server.

This is what I have checked so far:

- SQL Server is running
- SQL Server Browser is running
- SQL Server Agent is running
- Firewall is turned off for all three profiles (doamin, private, and public)
- Named Pipes and TCP/IP are enabled in SQL Server Network Configuration within the SQL Server Configuration Manager
- TCP/IP is set to 1433
- I can connect to the Alias via SQL Management Studio on the server
- I can ping the name of the alias
- I have a DNS A Record for the SQL Alias
- I created an entry in the HOSTS file (Just in case I screwed up the DNS A Record)
- SQL Browser is running
- The Domain account for the SQL Browser service is a SYSADMIN in SQL Server
- Running SQLCMD -L in CMD returns the name of my alias (and server)
- Remote connections are enabled in SQL Server Management Studio

This is driving me crazy.  What am I missing?

Comment: You are aware that Sql Server [is not a good idea](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2032911) on a DC?

Comment: This is a development VM.  I understand the implications but our developers need a simple 1 VM setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually rebuilt from scratch.  I think my problem was that I changed the SQL Browser Service Account but I cannot be sure.